# where does the pickle file get saved in the local system? And how to call and share the file to other user?

Tags: python

I am running a linear model and the model file is converted into a pickle file. However whenever i reboot my system i could call the pickle file and eventually have to rerun the train model. I would like to know where the pickle file get saved and whenever i want to share or call the pickle file what is the process?

```
import pickle
with open('model_pickle.obj','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model_lin1,f)
with open('model_pickle.obj','rb') as f:
    mp=pickle.load(f)
Age_prediction_lin2=mp.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: It's saved wherever you specify the filename.

Comment: Any specific line of code to check the file path?

Comment: What does that mean? The pickle file is `model_pick.obj` in whatever directory you were running the script.

Comment: Use an absolute pathname if you want to be sure that it's a specific directory.

Comment: `with open('/home/username/model_pick.obj', 'wb') as f:`

Comment: If you want control over where the pickle file gets written,  then specify the location: `open(r'c:\path\to\folder\model_pickle.obj','wb')` (or equivalent for your platform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Save the file wherever you want, specifing the path while running the pickle.dump() command:

`with open(r'C:\fullpath\model_pickle.obj', 'wb') as f:`
    `pickle.dump(model_lin1,f)`

2. Before saving your file, run these commands:

`import os`

`os.getcwd()`

it will print you current working directory, where the file will be saved.